# A0 poster why I cannot insert the graphics .png or .jpg?

Tags: png, a0poster

I have the following:

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}
.....
\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
```

....

```
\begin{figure}[H] 
\centerline{\hbox{
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{fig_for_body/fig1_1.png}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{fig_for_body/fig1_2.png}
}} 
 \caption{(a) ...
 (b) ....
 }
\label{fig:....}
\end{figure}
```

And cursor shows the error says:

```
Argument of \Gin@iii has an extra }
```

Why I cannot add png or jpg? it is working with pdf. I tried graphicx but it does not work either!

Comment: The key value syntax is only supported by package `graphicx`, *not* `graphics`.

Comment: but i did try graphicx and it does not work as i said before

Comment: Did you compile it with `latex` or `pdflatex`? The former does not support `png` and `jpg`.

Comment: there is just latex option. How can i change it to pdflatex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax with key value options:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{fig_for_body/fig1_1.png}
```

is added by package `graphicx`, therefore the package needs to be loaded:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Then it depends on the driver, which graphics types are supported.
PNG is supporte by pdfTeX, thus it works with `pdflatex`.

In case of `dvips`, you can convert the PNG file to EPS, e.g. using ImageMagicks' `convert`.

Then it is convenient to omit the extension:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{fig_for_body/fig1_1}
```

Then `pdflatex` will find the `.png` file and `latex`/`dvips` will use the `.eps` file.